# Elliptic equations and variational formulation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, partial-functions

**My question:** We now consider the following equation:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
-\Delta_x u+u(x)=f(x), \quad x \in \Omega \\
\left\langle\nabla_x u(x), \vec{n}(x)\right\rangle=g(x), \quad x \in \partial \Omega .
\end{array}\right.
$$
Prove that solutions of this equation satisfy the following variational equality: for any $v \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$,
$$
\int_{\Omega}\left(\nabla_x u(x) \cdot \nabla_x v(x)+u(x) v(x)\right) d x=\int_{\Omega} f(x) v(x) d x+\int_{\partial \Omega} g(x) v(x) d s(x) .
$$
Then, prove that any $u \in C^2(\bar{\Omega})$ satisfying the variational equality satisfies the equation above.
**My attempt**
Let's recall the integration by part formula
$u, w \in C^1(\bar{\Omega})$ and $i \in\{1, \ldots, N\}$
$$
\int_{\Omega} u(x) \frac{\partial w}{\partial x_i}(x) d x=-\int_{\Omega} w(x) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}(x) d x+\int_{\partial \Omega} u(x) w(x) d s(x)
$$
Using this formula with $w=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}(x)$, i can prove that
$$\int_{\Omega} \Delta_x u(x) v(x) d x=-\int_{\Omega} \nabla_x u(x) \cdot \nabla_x v(x) d x+\int_{\partial \Omega}\langle\nabla u(x), \vec{n}(x)\rangle v(x) d s(x)$$
Besides, we have $\Delta_x u=u(x) - f(x)$. That implies
$$\int_{\Omega}\left(\nabla_x u(x) \cdot \nabla_x v(x)+u(x) v(x)\right) d x=\int_{\Omega} f(x) v(x) d x+\int_{\partial \Omega} g(x) v(x) d s(x).$$
But i don't know how to deal with the next question: prove that any $u \in C^2(\bar{\Omega})$ satisfying the variational equality satisfies the equation above.

Comment: Hint: start with $v\in C^1_0(\Omega)$ to show that the PDE holds in ${\cal D}'(\Omega)$, hence almost everywhere since $\Delta u\in C^0$.

Comment: Can you explain more. Sorry, this is the first time i have approached PDE. If you can, please suggest me some books, in which i can find the solution for this problem.